# Git download optimization: pull once for entire office

Tags: git

The connection from our office to GitHub.com is often slow and files are often large.

Is there an easy way to use just one machine to sync with GitHub and let the others pull and push to that one over the LAN?

Answer (score 3):

As long as your colleagues have access to a common share drive, it can be enough to clone the GitHub repo on one workstation, and clone that local repo multiple times one the other workstations.

One person can be in charge of consolidating people's contribution to that intermediate repo before pushing back to GitHub.